# How to disable previous/next button?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, pagination, javascript-framework, jquery-pagination

i'm using jpages plugin for pagination,when first page is displaying previous button has to be disabled and while last page is displaying next button has to be disabled what change i need to do in jquery.pages.js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 updateBtns : function(nav, page) {
      if (page === 1) {
        nav.first.addClass("jp-disabled");
        nav.previous.addClass("jp-disabled");
      }
      if (page === this._numPages) {
        nav.next.addClass("jp-disabled");
        nav.last.addClass("jp-disabled");
      }
      if (this._currentPageNum === 1 && page > 1) {
        nav.first.removeClass("jp-disabled");
        nav.previous.removeClass("jp-disabled");
      }
      if (this._currentPageNum === this._numPages && page < this._numPages) {
        nav.next.removeClass("jp-disabled");
        nav.last.removeClass("jp-disabled");
      }
    },

    updateCurrentPage : function(nav, page) {
      nav.currentPage.removeClass("jp-current");
      nav.currentPage = nav.pages.eq(page - 1).addClass("jp-current");
    }
```

Comment: it is not working.prev/next button not getting disabled.am i need to insert any other content for this?

Comment: How to change the colour in 'jp-disabled' class?